# android intent filter : why separate them?

Tags: android, intentfilter

so i was reading the intent-filters paragraph from the doc, but i can't really understand why we separate the intent filters, like this example from the NotePad project :

```
<activity android:name="NoteEditor"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
                  android:label="@string/title_note" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_NOTE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So, we only accept an action that should be VIEW, or EDIT, or EDIT_NOTE ?
and why do we close this filter, and open a new one for the INSERT action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to close an `intent-filter` and add a new one for *INSERT*, because *INSERT* needs other data than the other `actions`. look at the different `mimeTypes` in the `data`

Comment: thanks ;-) okay it makes sense, and can you give me an example of a "note" whose type is a "dir" ? what could be the difference between those two datas?

Comment: read this, so get your answer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

"[...] The intent would contain the URI for data matching the MIME type vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note — that is, the URI for the directory where the note should be placed."